# Why do some symbolic links affect program behavior?

Tags: symlink, executable, filenames

One thing that has been puzzling me for some time is this:

```
% which halt
/sbin/halt
% file /sbin/halt
/sbin/halt: symbolic link to `reboot'
```

However, executing `sudo halt` does, of course, **not** reboot the system. Why is that?

There are several other programs working that way, for example `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every program can see the full command line that was used to run it (except for wildcards and variables, which the shell expands).

In a C program, the command line is stored in `argv`, which is short for *argument vector*.
The progam's name is the first element of `argv`, i.e. `argv[0]`.

Clearly in the case of `halt` and `reboot`, the program is changing its behavior based on `argv[0]`.

From bash, you can see the full command line used to run a program using `ps -p <pid> -o cmd` or `cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline`.

Note that there is another type of link called a hard link that will have the same effect.  On my system for example, `sudo` and `sudoedit` are the same file with two different names, and different behaviors.

`ls -i` can help you find those commands, e.g.:

```
$ ls -il | awk '$3 != 1 { print }'
total 156872
2491111 -rwsr-xr-x 2 root   root     127560 2011-01-20 05:03 sudo
2491111 -rwsr-xr-x 2 root   root     127560 2011-01-20 05:03 sudoedit
```

See `man ln` for more details about hard links if you're not familiar with them.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know symlinks behaved that way.

Comment: @legate, symlinks don't, applications can. the best example of a program that uses it's name to define how it executes is  `busybox`. symlinks are just the number one way of defining the 0th argument to an application. simply renaming a file would also suffice.

Comment: I failed to parse this one: *Note that there is also called a hard link that will have the same effect.*

Comment: I have re-written that sentence.  Hopefully it is clearer now.